# Expressão Regular está correta porém não entra no if

Tags: regex, bash, shell-script, shell

Gostaria de saber porque meu código não está entrando nesse `if` mais interno.

Testei o regex por uns sites e está funcionando. Testei com esse valor: `nucepe-2018-pc-pi-perito-criminal-informatica-prova.pdf`.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Declarando regex que vão ser utilizadas
regex_prova='(prova)'
regex_banca='((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))'
regex_ano='\b(19|20)\d{2}\b'
regex_orgao='.*?(?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*).*?((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))'
regex_cargo=

#Percorrendo todos os arquivos pdf na pasta
for file in *.pdf

do 
    #Pegando o nome do pdf
    str=$file

    #Verificando se existe a palavra prova no nome do arquivo
    if [[ $str =~ $regex_prova ]]; then

        #Pega qual é a banca
        if [[ $str =~ $regex_banca ]]; then

            echo $str  #Não entra aqui
            #echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}  #Não entra aqui
        else
            echo 'Erro na Regex_banca'
        fi

        #Pega qual é o ano da prova
        if [[ $str =~ $regex_ano ]]; then

            echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        else
            echo 'Erro no Regex_Ano'
        fi

    else
        echo 'Erro na Regex_prova'
    fi


done
```

Comment: Seria bom [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/340378/edit) a pergunta e explicar o como deseja capturar os dados! Você disse que testou e funcionou, comigo deu erro na expressão do ano e banca. Já adianto que a expressão para capturar o ano está incorreta, você pode fazer assim: `regex_ano='([[:digit:]]{4})'` ou assim: `regex_ano='([0-9]{4})'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema de regex é que existem vários *flavors* (sabores) diferentes. Eu diria que se regex fosse um idioma, ele teria vários dialetos (inclusive, em algumas documentações, essas variações são chamadas de "dialetos" mesmo).

Há [vários recursos](http://rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) previstos na sua sintaxe, mas cada linguagem e *engine* implementa um subconjunto delas. Há inclusive diferenças na sintaxe, então o que funciona em um ambiente pode não funcionar em outro. Por isso as expressões do seu script podem funcionar em alguns sites mas não no Bash.

Provavelmente os sites que você testou estão usando *engines* compatíveis com [**PCRE** (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html) ou alguma outra, enquanto o [**Bash**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions-1) usa o [**GNU ERE** (Extended Regular Expressions)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html).

Você pode entrar [nesta página](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refshorthand.html) e escolher nos dois combos no topo da página as opções "GNU ERE" e "PCRE" e ver que o atalho `\d` só é implementado pelo segundo:

[image: tabela mostrando que <code>\d</code> não é suportado pela engine GNU ERE]

`\d` é um atalho para "dígitos", e no **GNU ERE** podemos usar uma expressão equivalente, que é `[0-9]` - os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), ou seja, aceita tudo que estiver dentro deles. No caso, `[0-9]` significa "qualquer dígito de 0 a 9".

Já [nesta outra página](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) (também escolhendo "GNU ERE" e "PCRE" nos combos no topo da página), veja que o **GNU ERE** não suporta a sintaxe `(?:`, que é um [grupo de não-captura](http://rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#noncap).

Como você está usando a variável `BASH_REMATCH`, não faz sentido usar grupos de não-captura, já que eles são coisas opostas. [`BASH_REMATCH` vai guardar o que for capturado pelos parênteses](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions), mas apenas se estes forem um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (e para isso eles não podem estar com o `?:`). E de qualquer forma, o Bash não reconhece esta sintaxe, então podemos removê-la.

*E mesmo se reconhecesse, fazer `((?:alguma_coisa))` não faz sentido, pois é um grupo de não-captura (ou seja, algo que você não quer capturar para `BASH_REMATCH`) dentro de um grupo de captura (algo que você quer capturar)*.

Já o `\b` é um [atalho para *word boundary*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), algo como "fronteira de palavra" (ou seja, qualquer caractere que não faça parte de uma palavra, e cuja definição exata varia conforme o dialeto/engine/linguagem utilizado).

Para não depender destas variações, troquei por `[^0-9]`: o `^` dentro dos colchetes diz para negar tudo que tem dentro dele. Ou seja, `[^0-9]` significa "qualquer coisa que não seja um dígito de 0 a 9". Creio que isso seja o suficiente para separar o ano dos demais caracteres.

Resumindo, tire os grupos de não-captura (`(?:`) e troque `\d` por `[0-9]` e `\b` por `[^0-9]`. Então as expressões ficam assim:

```
regex_prova='prova'
regex_banca='([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)'
regex_ano='[^0-9]((19|20)[0-9]{2})[^0-9]'
```

Retirei os parênteses de `prova` porque você não está capturando este valor, somente testando-o, então não precisa dos parênteses.

O código fica conforme abaixo, mas atenção porque eu retirei o `for` (para facilitar os testes) e imprimi o *match* obtido usando `BASH_REMATCH` (esta variável é um array, e a posição 1 corresponde ao primeiro par de parênteses da regex):

```
str="nucepe-2018-pc-pi-perito-criminal-informatica-prova.pdf"

#Verificando se existe a palavra prova no nome do arquivo
if [[ $str =~ $regex_prova ]]; then

    #Pega qual é a banca
    if [[ $str =~ $regex_banca ]]; then
        echo  "Banca:" ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    else
        echo 'Erro na Regex_banca'
    fi

    #Pega qual é o ano da prova
    if [[ $str =~ $regex_ano ]]; then
        echo "Ano:" ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    else
        echo 'Erro no Regex_Ano'
    fi

else
    echo 'Erro na Regex_prova'
fi
```

A saída é:

```
Banca: nucepe
Ano: 2018
```

Se o ano sempre está entre hífens, você também pode trocar a regex para:

```
regex_ano='-((19|20)[0-9]{2})-'
```

---

**PS:** `regex_orgao` não foi usada no seu script, mas ela também tem alguns poréns. Ela faz uso de `.*?`: o ponto de interrogação depois do asterisco é um [*lazy quantifier* (quantificador preguiçoso)](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution). Basicamente, `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências", mas por padrão ele é "ganancioso", pois tenta pegar o maior número possível de caracteres. Usando `*?` ele se torna "preguiçoso", pegando o menor número possível de caracteres que satisfaça a expressão.

Mas infelizmente, se olharmos [nesta página](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) (e novamente escolhermos "GNU ERE" e "PCRE" nos combos no topo da página), veremos que o **GNU ERE** não suporta esta sintaxe.

[Testando a sua regex](https://regex101.com/r/C0PFLT/1) com o nome do arquivo que você usou, o valor obtido para o órgão foi `pc`. Neste caso, dá para simplificar a expressão para:

```
regex_orgao='([^\-]+-)([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)'
```

Repare que ela possui dois pares de parênteses, o que significa que `BASH_REMATCH` terá dois grupos (caso a string esteja de acordo com a regex). O primeiro grupo contém `[^\-]+-`, que significa:

- `[^\-]+`: uma ou mais ocorrências (`+`) de qualquer coisa que não seja um hífen (`[^\-]`). Como o hífen tem significado especial dentro dos colchetes (serve para definir um intervalo, como em `[0-9]`), eu precisei escapá-lo com `\`
- `-`: um hífen

Ou seja, são vários caracteres (que não sejam um hífen), seguidos de um hífen. Esta expressão assume que o hífen é o separador dos "campos" que compõem o nome do arquivo.

O segundo par de parênteses é o que você já estava usando:

- `[a-z]`: uma letra de `a` a `z`
- `[a-z0-9_]*`: zero ou mais ocorrências (`*`) de uma letra de `a` a `z` **ou** um dígito de 0 a 9 **ou** o caractere `_`

Ou seja, `regex_orgao` está pegando caracteres seguidos de um hífen, seguidos de "letra + letras ou números ou `_`". Por isso ela não pega o trecho `nucepe-2018`, já que depois do hífen tem somente números (ou seja, não corresponde ao trecho `[a-z]`).

O trecho que ela acaba pegando é `2018-pc`, sendo que `2018-` é capturado para o primeiro grupo (pois corresponde ao primeiro par de parênteses) e `pc` é capturado para o segundo grupo.

Para obter os valores destes grupos, basta fazer `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` e `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`. Mas como o que interessa parece ser somente o segundo parênteses, podemos descartar o primeiro. O trecho do script ficaria assim:

```
if [[ $str =~ $regex_orgao ]]; then
    echo "orgao: " ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```

E no caso, o órgão obtido é `pc`.